# How to share folder between host/guest?

Tags: virtualbox

I have two Ubuntu 22.04.1 installations. One host and one Virtual Box guest.
The guest has Additions installed. The userids are the same across host and guest.

Now, when I try to share a folder of `$HOME/Foo` from host to guest, I get an error message:

> Could not remove the shared folder 'Foo' (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).

which seems like bad error handling since it happens regardless whether there is a folder `Foo` on the guest, I rebooted the guest, etc.

When I however switch to Machine sharing, it at least creates the mount point. Then however I get an error when accessing the folder:

> Permission denied.

So I am wondering which user account VirtualBox is using to access the files on the host.

Does anyone know the technical steps to successfully share folders between installations of Ubuntu?

Comment: In the *guest client*, have you added your user to group `bvoxsf`? `usermod -a -G vboxsf $USER`

Comment: Thanks, that did it.